# Using a variable OUTFILE in a MySQL scheduled event

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using phpMyAdmin to try to schedule an event that runs every hour. I need it to select data from one of my tables and export it to **csv** that has a unique name which includes the current timestamp. Outside of an event, I can successfully output from my table to a **csv** like so:

```
SET @TimeStamp = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'__%Y_%m_%d__%H.%i.%s');

SELECT CONCAT(
    'SELECT form_value INTO OUTFILE \'D:/Websites/RTP/contact_form_data/form_data_',
    @TimeStamp,
    '.csv\' ',
    'FROM wp_db7_forms'
) INTO @SQL;

PREPARE stmt from @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to get this working in an event. phpMyAdmin doesn't give very specific error messages, but it seems that the event doesn't like the fact that I am using a variable (it also doesn't seem to like CONCAT). From my research, I've found that this may be because each event executes in a new session, and user-defined variables have session scope.

I tried creating a stored procedure to execute this same block of code, but that experiences similar issues.

Any ideas on an approach I can take to get my code to properly execute in an event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
SET @sql = 
CONCAT(
  'SELECT form_value INTO OUTFILE \'D:/Websites/RTP/contact_form_data/form_data_',
  DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'__%Y_%m_%d__%H.%i.%s'),
    '.csv\' ',
    'FROM wp_db7_forms'
) ;

PREPARE stmt from @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The session variable for time is not needed and the session variable @sql must be set as show in the code

This can be saved in mysql 8 and Workbench

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT export_contact_Form_data
 ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
 ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO BEGIN

    SET @sql =
    CONCAT(
      'SELECT form_value INTO OUTFILE \'D:/Websites/RTP/contact_form_data/form_data_',
      DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'__%Y_%m_%d__%H.%i.%s'),
        '.csv\' ',
        'FROM wp_db7_forms'
    ) ;
    PREPARE stmt from @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

This runs only once in one minute, so that you can i peace check 
every thing

and of course the delete query

```
DROP EVENT IF Exists export_contact_Form_data;
```

Comment: This isn't working because it's still trying to set a variable in the event. I think I need a way around using a variable.

Comment: Please show me the error message. Everything abouve should work in mysql

Comment: Unfortunately, phpMyAdmin doesn't give you much context. Here is where I am adding the event: https://imgur.com/a/O7Bnq8N and here is the error: https://imgur.com/a/pOtZMxS

Comment: I added my event so that you can run it in phpmyadmin.